# Vuelidate minvalue optionnal

Tags: vuejs2, vuelidate

I would like to validate a value 'stock' which is optionnal. I'm using vuelidate (https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/)

Value 'stock' must be greater than 0 if an other value ('price') is greater than 0

If 'price' value is not defined, the validator of stock value must be disabled

price is an input value (decimal number), stock is a slider (number)

[EDIT]

Example of code

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit" class="offer-form">
    <q-field label="Prix initial" helper="Indiquer le prix initial de l'offre" :error="hasItemError('price')" :error-label="itemErrorLabel('price')">
      <q-input type="number" color="input" @blur="$v.item.price.$touch()" v-model="item.price" />
    </q-field>                 
    <q-field label="Stock" helper="Indiquer le nombre de stock" :error="hasItemError('stock')" :error-label="itemErrorLabel('stock')">
      <q-slider color="input" label-always  label :step=1 :min="0" @blur="$v.item.stock.$touch()" :max="50" v-model="item.stock"/>
    </q-field>
    <q-btn
        icon="fas fa-check"
        label="Valider"
        color="green"
        @click="submit"
    />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { required, requiredIf, decimal, minValue } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      item: {
        id: null,
        title: '',
        description: '',
        price: null,
        reductionPercentage: 15,
        stock: 0,
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: null,
        product: null,
        shop: null,
        images: []
      },
  },
  validations: {
    item: {
      title: { required },
      startDate: { required },
      endDate: { required },
      price: { decimal },
      reductionPercentage: {
        requiredIf: requiredIf((vueInstance) => {
          return vueInstance.price > 0
        }),
        minValue: minValue(15)
      },
      stock: {
        requiredIf: requiredIf((vueInstance) => {
          return vueInstance.price > 0
        }),

        // minValue ???
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      this.onSubmit = true
      if (this.isValidate()) {
        // Validation ok
      }
      this.onSubmit = false
    },
    isValidate () {
      this.$v.item.$touch()
      if (this.$v.item.$error) {
        this.$q.notify({message: 'Vérifiez les champs en erreur', position: 'center'})
        return false
      }
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

I tested this but it's not ok =>

```
minValue: minValue((vueInstance) => {
   return vueInstance.price > 0 ? vueInstance.stock > 0 : true
})
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are strugling with this still, or there is anyone out there with the same issue, but here is my two cents:

```
minValue: (stockValue, item) => {
   return item.price > 0 ? stockValue > 0 : true
})
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You dont offer a lot of code so it is hard to understand your goal,but i will try,just tell me if it is what you wanted :)

Validator of Stock is a Checkbox or a function or ?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: 0,
    stock: 0,
  },
  
  computed: {
  stockvalidator: function()
  {
    if(this.price > 0 && this.stock > 0) return true
    else if(this.price > 0 && this.stock <= 0) return false
    else return false 
    
    
    
  }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">


  <input type="number" v-model="price">
  Price: {{price}}
  
  <input type="number" v-model="stock">
  Stock: {{stock}}
  
  <br>
  
  <input :disabled="!stockvalidator" type="checkbox"> Stock Validator is {{stockvalidator}}
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
stock: {
    requiredIf: requiredIf(() => {
      return this.price > 0 || this.price
    }),
    minvalue: helpers.withMessage(
      "The minimum value for the stock is 0",
      helpers.withAsync(async value => {
        let retvalue;
        if(this.price > 0 && value > 0){
          retvalue = true;
        }
        else if (this.price > 0 && value <= 0){
          retvalue = false;
        }
        else{
          retvalue = true;
        }
        return retvalue;
      })
    )
  }
```

Remember import "helpers" from vuelidate.

And I advise you to make your own file with your custom validators, then you can use it in every places in your project. Something like utils/customValidators.js.